Flutter Error: 'Bad state: Stream has already been listened to' Occurs Only on Small Android Devices in Android Studio
I'm developing an attendance app for Android using Flutter with GetX and Firebase. The code works perfectly fine on most Android devices, especially those with screen sizes around 4.65 to 5.5 inches. However, I encounter an error when running the app on smaller Android phones:

Error: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

This issue seems to only occur on small-screen devices. I'm unsure why this happens, as the code runs without issues on other devices. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
Error
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StateError was thrown building Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0), bg: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffdfd3c3), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0))):
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container Container:file:///D:/Kuliah/PROYEK/PRESENSI_APP_V.1.0.4/fluttercode/presensiapp/lib/app/modules/home/views/home_view.dart:119:17
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState._subscribe (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:130:38)
#4      _StreamBuilderBaseState.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:104:5)
#5      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5748:55)
#6      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5593:5)
...     Normal element mounting (53 frames)
#59     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4468:16)
#60     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3963:18)
#61     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:967:37)
#62     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:952:20)
#63     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3038:19)
#64     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:944:12)
#65     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:361:23)
#66     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2719:59)
#67     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1098:15)
#68     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2719:14)
#69     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:350:5)
#70     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutLeadingChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:468:5)
#71     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:126:29)
#72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2608:7)
#73     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:121:12)
#74     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:327:11)
#75     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2608:7)
#76     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:601:13)
#77     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1516:12)
#78     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1427:20)
#79     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2446:7)
#80     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1052:18)
#81     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1065:15)
#82     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:602:23)
#83     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1164:13)
#84     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:468:5)
#85     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1397:15)
#86     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1318:9)
#87     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1176:5)
#88     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#89     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:419:5)
#90     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================

home_view.dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:presensiapp/app/routes/app_pages.dart';
import '../controllers/home_controller.dart';
import '../../../controllers/page_index_controller.dart';

class HomeView extends GetView<HomeController> {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final pageC = Get.find<PageIndexController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('HOME'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(248, 237, 227, 1),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Image.asset(
                'assets/unipaa2.png'
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: controller.streamUser(),
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            Map<String, dynamic> user = snapshot.data!.data()!;
            String defaultImage = "https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name=${user['name']}";
            return ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    ClipOval(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 75,
                        height: 75,
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 211, 195, 1),
                        child: Image.network(
                            user["profile"] != null
                                ? user["profile"]
                                : defaultImage,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 10,),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Selamat Datang',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width: 200,
                          child: Text(
                              user["address"] != null
                                  ? '${user["address"]}'
                                  : 'Belum Ada Lokasi',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 211, 195, 1),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '${user['job']}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
                      Text(
                        '${user['npp']}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        '${user['name']}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 211, 195, 1),
                  ),
                  child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                    stream: controller.streamTodayPresence(),
                    builder: (context, snapToday) {
                      if(snapToday.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      Map<String, dynamic>? dataToday = snapToday.data?.data();
                      return Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                  "MASUK",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5,),
                              Text(
                                  dataToday?["masuk"] == null
                                      ? "-"
                                      : "${DateFormat.Hms().format(DateTime.parse(dataToday!['masuk']['date']))}"
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: 2,
                            height: 40,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                  "KELUAR",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5,),
                              Text(
                                  dataToday?["keluar"] == null
                                      ? "-"
                                      : "${DateFormat.Hms().format(DateTime.parse(dataToday!['keluar']['date']))}"
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20,),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  thickness: 2,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Presensi 5 Hari Terakhir',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.ALL_PRESENSI),
                      child: Text(
                        'Riwayat Presensi',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(248, 237, 227, 1),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                  stream: controller.streamLastPresence(),
                  builder: (context, snapPresence) {
                    if(snapPresence.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    if(snapPresence.data?.docs.length == 0 || snapPresence.data == null){
                      return SizedBox(
                        height: 150,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Belum Ada Riwayat Presensi"
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: snapPresence.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        Map<String, dynamic> data = snapPresence.data!.docs[index].data();
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                          child: Material(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(223, 211, 195, 1),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () => Get.toNamed(
                                Routes.DETAIL_PRESENSI,
                                arguments: data,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          'Masuk',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          "${DateFormat.yMMMEd().format(DateTime.parse(data['date']))}",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      data['masuk']?['date'] == null
                                          ? '-'
                                          : '${DateFormat.Hms().format(DateTime.parse(data['masuk']?['date']))}',
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    Text(
                                      'Keluar',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      data['keluar']?['date'] == null
                                          ? '-'
                                          : '${DateFormat.Hms().format(DateTime.parse(data['keluar']?['date']))}',
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Tidak dapat memuat database user"),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
        style: TabStyle.fixedCircle,
        items: [
          TabItem(icon: Icons.home, title: 'Home',),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.fingerprint, title: 'Presensi'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.people, title: 'Profil'),
        ],
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(141, 73, 48, 1),
        initialActiveIndex: pageC.pageIndex.value,
        onTap: (int i) => pageC.changePage(i),
      ),
    );
  }
}

home_controller.dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:internet_connection_checker_plus/internet_connection_checker_plus.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    checkInternet();
  }

  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamUser() async* {
    String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

    yield* firestore.collection("pegawai").doc(uid).snapshots();
  }
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamLastPresence() async* {
    String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

    yield* firestore
        .collection("pegawai")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection("presence")
        .orderBy("date", descending: true)
        .limit(5)
        .snapshots();
  }


  Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamTodayPresence() async* {
    String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

    String todayID = DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.now()).replaceAll("/", "-");

    yield* firestore.collection("pegawai").doc(uid).collection("presence").doc(todayID).snapshots();
  }

  Future<void> checkInternet() async {
    bool cekInternet = await InternetConnection().hasInternetAccess;
    if (!cekInternet) {
      Get.snackbar("TERJADI KESALAHAN", "TIDAK ADA KONEKSI INTERNET, SILAHKAN CEK KONEKSI INTERNET ANDA !");
    }
  }
}

I'm developing a Flutter app that utilizes Firestore and Streams for real-time data fetching. I have three functions (streamUser, streamLastPresence, and streamTodayPresence) that return data from Firestore as BroadcastStreams. I used asBroadcastStream() to allow the stream to have multiple listeners.
However, even after converting the streams to BroadcastStreams, I'm still encountering the following error when trying to display the data in a widget:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.

Here is the code I used:
Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamUser() {
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

  // Converting to broadcast stream
  return firestore.collection("pegawai").doc(uid).snapshots().asBroadcastStream();
}

Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamLastPresence() {
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

  // Converting to broadcast stream
  return firestore
      .collection("pegawai")
      .doc(uid)
      .collection("presence")
      .orderBy("date", descending: true)
      .limit(5)
      .snapshots()
      .asBroadcastStream();
}

Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamTodayPresence() {
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

  String todayID = DateFormat.yMd().format(DateTime.now()).replaceAll("/", "-");

  // Converting to broadcast stream
  return firestore.collection("pegawai").doc(uid).collection("presence").doc(todayID).snapshots().asBroadcastStream();
}

Despite converting the streams with asBroadcastStream(), the "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to" error persists. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

streamTodayPresence is not a broadcast stream - this stream makes your problems - the error says it's line #119 of home_view.dart

returnfirestore.collection("pegawai").doc(uid).collection("presence").doc(todayID).snapshots().asBroadcastStream();
I have tried changing to a broadcast stream, but the error still occurs. Note that this error only happens on small Android devices.

so where is error now? what's the top of the stacktrace?

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StateError was thrown building Container(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0), bg: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffdfd3c3), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0))):
Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Container Container:file:///D:/Kuliah/PROYEK/PRESENSI_APP_V.1.0.4/fluttercode/presensiapp/lib/app/modules/home/views/home_view.dart:119:17
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
